# Encoding PrivateKey in PKCS#1 format, then restoring to PrivateKey

Tags: java, kotlin, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

I have a 2048-bit RSA PublicKey that I wish to convert into a PKCS#1 formatted ByteArray, and then restore the PublicKey object from that ByteArray. I'm converting to PKCS#1 with BouncyCastle using Kotlin on the JVM with the following code:

```
fun privKeyToPkcs1Bytes(privKey: PrivateKey): ByteArray {
    val privKeyInfo = PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(privKey.encoded)
    val privKeyAsn1Encodable: ASN1Encodable = privKeyInfo.parsePrivateKey()
    val privKeyAsn1Primitive: ASN1Primitive = privKeyAsn1Encodable.toASN1Primitive()
    val privKeyPkcs1Bytes: ByteArray = privKeyAsn1Primitive.getEncoded()
    return privKeyPkcs1Bytes
}
```

and then I'm trying to restore the returned ByteArray to a PrivateKey object using the following code:

```
fun privKeyFromPkcs1Bytes(privKeyPkcs1Bytes: ByteArray): PrivateKey {
    val rsaPrivKey: RSAPrivateKey = RSAPrivateKey.getInstance(ASN1Sequence.fromByteArray(privKeyPkcs1Bytes))
    val privKeySpec: RSAPrivateKeySpec = RSAPrivateKeySpec(rsaPrivKey.modulus, rsaPrivKey.privateExponent)
    val privKey: PrivateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(privKeySpec)
    return privKey
}
```

The code runs without error, but the PKCS#8 representations of the original PrivateKey and restored PrivateKey do not match. I have thoroughly searched for a resolution to this issue, and haven't found a solution that works. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you want the "full" RSA Private key format you must provide all the components and use [`RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec.html) which is a subclass of `RSAPrivateKeySpec`. But you should be aware that, even then, there is no guarantee that the round-trip from PKCS1 or PKCS8 bytes to Java objects and back to bytes will produce  byte-for-byte identical representations. This is because in PKCS1 (and PKCS8) the order of the primes p and q is not specified.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks for the fix, and the advice. I need to share keys between iOS, Android and JVM projects, hence my need to restore key objects from bytes. Do you know of a better way to do this, given the lack of specificity with regard to prime order?

Comment: I'm not familiar with iOS but I suspect that PKCS8 is the most interoperable format. The reason prime order isn't specified is because it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I've run into an issue; it doesn't involve iOS or Android, just JVM. I'm converting public RSA keys to X509 format, then to PKCS1 format, encoding them as strings and saving them in a database. Then, I'm retrieving the strings, restoring them to PKCS1 format, then to X509 format, and then to a PublicKey object. When I println() the original PublicKey object and the restored one, I see they have the same modulus and exponent; equating them returns true. Yet for some reason, their X509 encodings are different. Any idea why this may be?